# Economics.SE is closing, can we salvage some of the questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

I hadn't even heard that there was an [Economics Stack Exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com) site before I learned that [it will be closed down next week](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/) along with a bunch of other quiescent beta sites.

> **Update:** As planned, the original Economics Stack Exchange was shut down shortly after I posted this back in 2012.  A few years later, in 2014, a *new* Economics site was created at the same URL, and as of 2019 seems to be doing fine.  This meta post is thus now only a historical curiosity.  Sorry for any confusion!
>
> <sup>As a side effect of shutting down the site and recreating it from scratch, the database (including all post and user IDs) was reset.  Thus, any links to questions on the old Economics site below will, if clicked, now take you to a random question (or answer) on the new site that just happens to have the same ID number.  I have <s>struck out</s> such broken links in this post.</sup>

It now looks like many of the other sites are going to be fully or partially [absorbed into more active SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130342/salvage-questions-on-closed-sites-via-migration) with overlapping topics, where their question can remain on the web and receive the tender care of an active community.  However, no-one seems to have expressed an interest in Economics.SE yet.

Math.SE does have an [economics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics) tag.  A quick look at the Economics.SE front page suggests that many of their 412 questions so far would be on topic for us.  Here are a few random examples:

- <s>[Cournot Nash Equilibrium Between Two Firms](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/cournot-nash-equilibrium-between-two-firms)</s>
- <s>[What are the relevant properties of cardinal utility functions for defining a notion of expected utility for mixed strategies in games?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/287/what-are-the-relevant-properties-of-cardinal-utility-functions-for-defining-a-no)</s>
- <s>[Can someone explain Cremer-Mclean's astonishing result in auction theory?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/546/can-someone-explain-cremer-mcleans-astonishing-result-in-auction-theory)</s>
- <s>[Game-theory strategies to overcome holdout problem?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/493/game-theory-strategies-to-overcome-holdout-problem)</s>
- <s>[Markov Perfect Equilibrium with Incomplete Information](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/667/markov-perfect-equilibrium-with-incomplete-information)</s>
- <s>[Nash equilibria of mixed strategies](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/nash-equilibria-of-mixed-strategies)</s>

Some of the questions over there may be a bit "soft" for us (but then, we're not MO), and some may suffer from a lack of good answers (after all, there's a reason why the site's being closed down), but I do believe that many of them would fit in here.

Of course, we're no the only Stack Exchange site that could adopt some of these questions; besides [Stats.SE (a.k.a. Cross Validated)](http://stats.stackexchange.com), there are also beta SE sites for [Quantitative Finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com) and [Personal Finance and Money](http://money.stackexchange.com).  Some of the more computationally oriented questions might also find a home on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), or perhaps on the [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange beta.  Then there's also [Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com) for behavioral economics, and [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com) for economic history questions.

(Whee, I had no idea there were *that* many SE beta sites around!)

I've <s>[posted about this on the Economics meta](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/salvaging-questions-by-migration)</s>, but I'd like to request opinions and help from the Math.SE community here.  If you'd like to help in keeping the more mathematical questions from Economics.SE on the web, here's what you can do:

- Express your support for the migration process, so that the SE folks can tell that the community here is (as I hope, at least) in favor of it.
- Go through the list of [questions on Economics.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions) and look for ones that could be usefully migrated here.
- Collect links to the questions here, so that we can point an Economics mod at them before the site closes ([example of such a list at SF&F meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/literature-is-closing-what-questions-should-we-migrate-here)).  Or you could just flag the questions for migration directly, but this way we avoid needless duplicate flags.

Comment: Ouch, Theoretical Physics is also shutting down. For econ: I am not familiar with any of the topics you listed, so I will have no opinion.

Comment: Fortunately, [Theoretical Physics will probably be absorbed into Physics.SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/full-migration-of-theoretical-physics-se-questions-to-physics-se), so the content (and hopefully at least some of the community) will live on.

Comment: Just a note: there are only 412 questions on Econ.SE, so Ilmari's request that someone familiar with the subject take a look at the site to look for salvageable material isn't really that much work.

Comment: @WillieWong Not to be a drag, but I would think `game theory` would end up on Statistics.

Comment: @Aarthi: Why so? [Game theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) is a well established branch of mathematics, not of statistics. Besides, we have a [tag:game-theory] tag, stats.SE doesn't.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Ahhh. Okay, well then if that's the case, then huzzah! :D I always thought of game theory as a stats thing, but that's because I always was doing game theory work with econometric work. If it's math-y, then yay a new home.

Comment: @Ilmari: If you hadn't even realized there was an economics site and now it's closing down due to lack of interest, why is it important to migrate questions from there to math.SE?

Comment: @KCd: Some of them are pretty good questions (or at least have good answers). Some are even pretty decent math questions that just got posted there because they're about math as applied to economics. It would seem a shame to just dump them all into a database backup somewhere and forget about them.

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17545/18398

Comment: I'm confused. Nearly eight years after its impending demise was reported here, the Econ site seems to exist and to be accepting posts. Did it get a reprieve?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The "Economics SE" site that this post mentions was closed. (You can see the Area 51 stats [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics).) Later _another_ Economics SE site was [proposed](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics), and _that_ one continues to this day.

Comment: @Meta, thanks. I can see from the answer that was posted a few hours ago that I wasn't the only one confused.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is obsolete. The old Economics site which this post is about was shut down in 2012, and a new site was created in its place in 2014.

Answer (score 10):

### Game theory questions

Out of the 11 questions tagged as [game-theory](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory), I believe the following could be on topic here:

- <del>[Game-theory strategies to overcome holdout problem?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/493/game-theory-strategies-to-overcome-holdout-problem)</del> (Migrated to cogsci.SE.)
- [What are the relevant properties of cardinal utility functions for defining a notion of expected utility for mixed strategies in games?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/287/what-are-the-relevant-properties-of-cardinal-utility-functions-for-defining-a-no)
- [Markov Perfect Equilibrium with Incomplete Information](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/667/markov-perfect-equilibrium-with-incomplete-information)
- $\star$ [Mechanism to auction off multiple resources given fixed budgets](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/595/mechanism-to-auction-off-multiple-resources-given-fixed-budgets)
- [Why must a preference relation for an agent be over a set of alternatives for which they can choose from instead of any set?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/837/why-must-a-preference-relation-for-an-agent-be-over-a-set-of-alternatives-for-wh)
- [Auctions for public goods](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/367/auctions-for-public-goods) (Maybe. Again, the answer and comments are more mathematical than the question.)
- [Cournot game and Bertrand game: Are they classes of game?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/73/cournot-game-and-bertrand-game-are-they-classes-of-game) (This is kind of soft, but I feel it would be in scope as a terminology question.)
- $\star$ [Nash equilibria of mixed strategies](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/nash-equilibria-of-mixed-strategies)

I also flagged [Can game theory explain grade inflation?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/99/can-game-theory-explain-grade-inflation) for possible migration to [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com).  That leaves two questions — [Can misalignment in incentives within organisations be modelled using game theory?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/289/can-misalignment-in-incentives-within-organisations-be-modelled-using-game-theor) and [Do “loss leaders” kill independent markets?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/501/do-loss-leaders-kill-independent-markets) — that I couldn't think of a good migration target for.

### Homework questions

It also turns out that many of the questions tagged as [homework](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) are fairly mathematical in nature (who'd have thought?).

- [Why would a monopolist never produce at the inelastic part of the demand curve?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/337/why-would-a-monopolist-never-produce-at-the-inelastic-part-of-the-demand-curve)
- $\star$ [Cournot Nash Equilibrium Between Two Firms](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/cournot-nash-equilibrium-between-two-firms)
- $\star$ [How can I reconcile these two different equations for “Arc Elasticity”?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-reconcile-these-two-different-equations-for-arc-elasticity)
- [Do we call it “consumer surplus”?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/do-we-call-it-consumer-surplus) (Marginal. It's a terminology question, and it's economics terminology, not math. But I'm feeling generous.)
- [Change in parameter b of a demand curve, equilibrium profit and elasticity](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/change-in-parameter-b-of-a-demand-curve-equilibrium-profit-and-elasticity)
- $\star$ [Application of the Factor–Price equalization theorem (Samuelson) on trade?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/721/application-of-the-factorprice-equalization-theorem-samuelson-on-trade)
- [Theory of the firm](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/543/theory-of-the-firm) (...or maybe not. It's a math problem, but it makes little sense unless you know the unstated definitions it's based on.)
- $\star$ [What's the most straight-forward way to prove Walras's Law?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/532/whats-the-most-straight-forward-way-to-prove-walrass-law)
- [Choosing a profit-maximizing output given two markets](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/340/choosing-a-profit-maximizing-output-given-two-markets) (Kind of basic, but OK, I guess.)
- [Construction Economics - Compounding discounting](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/construction-economics-compounding-discounting) (Recent question, no answer yet.)
- [Difference-in-difference estimator (panel data)](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/difference-in-difference-estimator-panel-data) (Again, sort of basic.)
- [Monopolist behaviour](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/851/monopolist-behaviour)
- $\star$ [How to find the minimum variance portfolio?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/816/how-to-find-the-minimum-variance-portfolio)
- [How can I set up a general equilibrium model for a 2-commodity economy?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/637/how-can-i-set-up-a-general-equilibrium-model-for-a-2-commodity-economy) (Maybe. It's an old unanswered homework question, and it does presuppose some knowledge of microeconomic theory, but it could perhaps be answerable here.)
- $\star$ [How to show that Roy's identity holds in the case of a monotonic increasing transformation?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/531/how-to-show-that-roys-identity-holds-in-the-case-of-a-monotonic-increasing-tran)
- [Marginal cost and benefit](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/marginal-cost-and-benefit) (Maybe. Again, it's mainly a terminology question, even if there's some math involved too.)
- [price, demand, market equilibrium](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/price-demand-market-equilibrium) (Migrated once from quant.SE. Does presume some background knowledge of economic theory. I tried to check whether the answer given is correct but gave up, I'm too tired.)
- $\star$ [Given supply and demand curves, and a tax, how can I find the tax burdens and revenue?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/409/given-supply-and-demand-curves-and-a-tax-how-can-i-find-the-tax-burdens-and-re)

As noted, some of these are far from perfect, but they at least fall on the right side of my (perhaps somewhat inclusionist) line of "Would I vote to close this if I saw it here?"
By the way, these lists are roughly in decreasing order of votes.  I'm seeing something of a trend here, with the lowest scoring questions being more often suitable for migration, which is perhaps not so surprising.

I'll stop here for now, since it's late and I'm tired.  I'll try to look through some more questions tomorrow, but in the mean time, feel free to look at these and strike out any that you'd rather not have migrated here.

**Edit:** I've flagged the questions marked with a $\star$ for migration here.  I'll leave the rest for later consideration, and/or for others to flag if they feel they belong here.  (Besides, I'm all out of flags now.)